# Google Apps Script - Get sheets by tab color

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am curious if there is a way to get sheets by the color of their tabs within Google Script?

I currently use this array to grab the sheets by name:

```js
function AddRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheetId');
  var contractorSheets,i,L,sheet;
contractorSheets = [
  "Employee 1's Timesheet",
  "Employee 2's Timesheet",
  "Employee 3's Timesheet",
  "Employee 4's Timesheet",
  "Employee 5's Timesheet",
  "Employee 6's Timesheet",
  "Employee 7's Timesheet"
]
L = contractorSheets.length;
for (i=0;i<L;i++){
  sheet = ss.getSheetByName(contractorSheets[i]);
  sheet.insertRowAfter(sheet.getLastRow());
  }
}
```

Timesheets are constantly being created and deleted, and I would have to update this array every time that happens. However, all the timesheet tabs are orange (#ff9900) so I figured if I could pull tabs by that color, it wouldn't matter what the name was and in the long run, make the spreadsheet a lot more dynamic regardless of turnover and sheet names.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
function addRow() {
SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyPz4').getSheets()
    .filter(function (sh) {
        return sh.getTabColor() == '#ff9900'; //change to match color
    }).forEach(function (sh) {
        sh.insertRowAfter(sh.getLastRow());
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done using already available methods:

```
function getSheetsWithTabColor_(colorHex, allSheets) {
  if (!allSheets || !allSheets.length)
    allSheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
  return allSheets.filter(function (sheet) { return sheet.getTabColor() === colorHex; });
}

function foo() {
  const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
  const timesheets = getSheetsWithTabColor_("some color hex", sheets);
  timesheets.forEach(function (sheet) {
    /** do your stuff that should be done on sheets with this color tab */
  });
}
```

References

- [`Sheet#getTabColor`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#gettabcolor)
- [`Spreadsheet#getSheets`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)
- [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)